# How to have absolute url with Hateoas Bundle on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, hateoas

I just fresh installed the bundle from Willdurant's github and I got relative url like this:

```
"_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/1.0/users/?page=1&limit=10"
    },
    "first": {
      "href": "/1.0/users/?page=1&limit=10"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "/1.0/users/?page=2&limit=10"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "/1.0/users/?page=2&limit=10"
    }
  }
```

For my Hateoas url, I really prefer absolute url but I don't find anything on google to change that. 2 hours of search, trying multiple keywords and nothing...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your code that produce this output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it many ways. All depends on the way of generating links.

If you use `@Route` annotation to generate link, it has a parameter `absolute` that need to be set to `true`:

```
/**
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *     name = "self",
 *     href = @Hateoas\Route(
 *         "user_get",
 *         parameters = { "id" = "expr(object.getId())" },
 *         absolute = true
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

If you use expression language to generate link you can pass `true` as third parameter to the `link()` function:

```
/**
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *     "user",
 *     href = "expr(link(object.getUser(), 'self', true))"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: My links you see in my post are auto-generated by the bundle for pagination, this is why I don't know how to change those without change vendor code. Otherwise, for relations, you're right, thanks for your samples!